# Fast matrix operations in R

Tags: r, performance, matrix-multiplication, microbenchmark

A couple of simple questions:

1. I want to build a matrix `X` of the following type:

```
N = 1000
A = seq(1, N, 1)
B = A
X = A %*% t(rep(1,N)) - rep(1,N) %*% t(B)
```

Working with this matrix `X` is kind of slow: it takes a lot of memory for large `N`, and doing matrix multiplications for it does not use the linear structure, which I suppose could be helpful(?).

Therefore, I want to avoid this, and the question is: what is the fastest way of calculating `X` (whenever I need it), possibly without creating the matrices `A %*% t(rep(1,N))` and `rep(1,N) %*% t(B)`?

2. What's the fastest approach for different sorts of matrix multiplications nowadays? There are some new packages, which are supposedly fast, but it seems that base R still dominates?

```
library(microbenchmark)
A = array(rnorm(10^4), c(100,100))
B = array(rnorm(10^4), c(100,100))


microbenchmark(fastmatrix::hadamard(A,B), A*B,Rfast::mat.mult(A,B), A %*%B, Rfast::Crossprod(A,B), t(A)%*%B)

Unit: microseconds
                       expr     min       lq      mean   median       uq      max neval
 fastmatrix::hadamard(A, B) 174.626 264.2185 303.55052 277.3510 301.7825 1052.063   100
                      A * B   3.711  29.9485  28.81842  31.5185  33.9670   73.038   100
      Rfast::mat.mult(A, B) 760.087 839.6020 918.76155 891.4790 944.5455 1356.274   100
                    A %*% B 500.756 536.6595 602.09226 565.5765 601.5310 1502.310   100
     Rfast::Crossprod(A, B) 716.953 786.3320 854.55307 813.4165 874.3930 1589.097   100
                 t(A) %*% B 520.544 585.2830 666.63137 631.3350 703.5430 1322.987   100
```

Comment: Given the lack of `Rcpp` content here, I am editing out the `rcpp` tag.

Comment: Note that having two questions on the same post is confusing and you might get less answers because of that. I'd suggest to post your second question in another post.

Comment: I find the heterogeneity of operations in benchmarks here distracting. I think the question would be clearer if only the operation of interest (`A %*% B`) and equivalents are included. Specifically, including element-wise multiplication (`A * B`) might lead to some misinterpretations that it is somehow "better", whereas it is simply a totally different operation.

Comment: I've tried a couple of options with the `collapse::flag` package, supposedly very fast, and `row() - col()`, but nothing beats your techniques so far. A better understanding of how and why you create this matrix could help.

Comment: Also note that there are a wide range of optimized/parallelized BLAS packages available, which may help you out ... https://simplystatistics.org/posts/2016-01-21-parallel-blas-in-r/, https://bookdown.org/rdpeng/rprogdatascience/parallel-computation.html#hidden-parallelism

Comment: Rfast's algorithms run in parallel. You need more than 1000*1000 size to see difference in time.

Answer (score 2):

To answer your first question:

```r
NN <- c(N, N)
Y <- .row(NN) - .col(NN)

identical(`storage.mode<-`(Y, "double"), X)
## [1] TRUE
```

Probably not much slower or faster than your code (depending on your BLAS implementation), but certainly more transparent and typically more *efficient*, giving a result of type `integer`, not `double`.  The "gotcha" here is that BLAS routines want `double`, so *computing* with the result can require a coercion ...

To answer your second question, note that `Y' = -Y`, hence `Y` is "skew-symmetric":

```r
identical(t(Y), -Y)
## [1] TRUE
```

Depending on what you are trying to do, you can take advantage of the fact that (IIRC) skew-symmetric matrices can be factorized as `LDL'`.  Whether there is a package implementing that factorization (using it to solve linear systems, etc.) remains to be seen, but I am doubtful.

If what you are trying to do is just matrix multiplication, then I would not expect skew-symmetry to help at all, unless you are wanting to write specialized Fortran routines of your own, modeled after `DSYMM` ...

Comment: I've never seen `.row` used before! Nice. But is it faster than what's proposed by OP?