Faster way to do element wise multiplication of matrices and scalar multiplicatión of matrices in R
i am doing element wise multiplication of large matrices, so i want to know if there is any way to do it faster than using the * operator from de R Base. I have been trying to find out but most of the questions and information is oriented to matrix multiplication.
we can try with the next example
A<- matrix(rnorm(10000),ncol =100 )
B<- matrix(rnorm(10000),ncol =100 )
A*B # Is there a faster way for this operation?
A*5000 # Is there a faster way for escalar multiplication?


I'm kinda amazed that the base R operation isn't fast enough for you. Is it possible you're running into memory problems if your matrices are truly that large? The base operator performs almost instantaneously for me on even matrices with 10k rows and columns.

Can you be more specific about the dimensions/scale of your data, the performance that you're observing, and your expectations/goal for that? Perhaps these prior questions are relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35923787/fast-large-matrix-multiplication-in-r or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77301772/how-to-perform-matrix-multiplication-in-r-faster-than or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76681052/fast-matrix-operations-in-r

The only way I'm seeing is with RcppParallel.

Median time for A*B is 10.8 µs on my system. Do you really need an improvement?

I'm pretty new to writing code in C++ so there might be a better approach than mine, but I was able to considerably speed up matrix scalar multiplication using Rcpp, but elementwise matrix multiplication using my Rcpp code is still slower than base R. I'm not sure if there's a faster way to do this using C++ code. Maybe if you combine it with RcppParallel, which I'm not sure how to use, it might be able to do elementwise multiplication faster than base R. But isn't it fast enough already? In my tests below, A and B have 1,000,000 rows and 100 columns and using base R elementwise multiplication still takes just about a fifth of a second.
library(Rcpp)

cppFunction('
NumericMatrix matrix_multiplication_elementwise(NumericMatrix A, NumericMatrix B) {
  int nrow = A.nrow(), ncol = A.ncol();
  NumericMatrix C(nrow, ncol);
  
  double* ptrA = A.begin();
  double* ptrB = B.begin();
  double* ptrC = C.begin();
  
  for (int i = 0; i < nrow * ncol; i++) {
    ptrC[i] = ptrA[i] * ptrB[i];
  }
  
  return C;
}
')


cppFunction('
NumericMatrix matrix_scalar_multiplication(NumericMatrix A, double scalar) {
  
  int nrow = A.nrow(), ncol = A.ncol();
  int n = nrow * ncol;
  
  
  double* ptrA = A.begin();
  
  
  for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    ptrA[i] *= scalar;
  }
  
  
  return A;
}
')


A <- matrix(rnorm(10^8),ncol =100 )
B <- matrix(rnorm(10^8),ncol =100 )

#Shows the results are identical
print(identical(A * B, matrix_multiplication_elementwise(A, B)))
print(identical(A * 5, matrix_scalar_multiplication(A, 5)))

microbenchmark::microbenchmark(A*B, 
                               matrix_multiplication_elementwise(A, B),
                               A*5,
                               matrix_scalar_multiplication(A, 5),
                               times = 5)


unit: milliseconds

| expr                                      |    min    |     lq    |   mean    | median   |     uq     |    max    | neval |
|:------------------------------------------|----------:|----------:|----------:|---------:|----------:|----------:|------:|
| A * B                                     |  134.4406 |  146.4602 |  179.6306 |  184.5839 |  199.9494 |  232.7189 |     5 |
| matrix_multiplication_elementwise(A, B)   |  209.8883 |  220.0424 |  236.6720 |  226.0925 |  232.0621 |  295.2745 |     5 |
| A * 5                                     |  123.2365 |  129.1649 |  169.9334 |  158.4771 |  159.5936 |  279.1949 |     5 |
| matrix_scalar_multiplication(A, 5)        |   58.9209 |   60.2994 |   65.6868 |   60.6691 |   63.1034 |   85.4412 |     5 |


the reason for the scalar multiplication being faster in your case is because it avoids matrix copying and also the overheads used by base R. this function does inplace replacement which is an unintended behaviour. R does not change its inputs while thius function does.
